# How to remove duplicated values with Mode in SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm using GCP BigQuery and my tables.

I want to remove duplicated values in Col1 and get Mode(most appearing value) in Col2.

[Source Table]

| Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | BB |
| 2 | BB |
| 3 | CC |
| 1 | AA |
| 1 | AA |
| 1 | DD |
| 2 | BB |
| 2 | EE |

[Expected Result]

| Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | AA |
| 2 | BB |
| 3 | CC |

Can I get the expected result using just one query?
Or what do I need? (temp tables, procedure or something like that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method uses two levels of aggregation:

```
select col1,
       (array_agg(col2 order by cnt desc limit 1))[ordinal(1)] as mode
from (select col1, col2, count(*) as cnt
      from t
      group by col1, col2
     ) cc
group by col1;
```

The above uses arrays, which are rather specific to BigQuery, another method uses window functions and conditional aggregation:

```
select col1,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then col2 end) as mode
from (select col1, col2, count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by col1 order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from t
      group by col1, col2
     ) cc
group by col1;
```